# Question about coupling of two Geometric random variables

Tags: probability-theory, coupling

Statement: Let $Z_{2t}$ and $Z_t$ be two geometric random variables of mean $2t$ and $t$ respectively, then by the coupling of $Z_{2t}$ and $Z_{t}$, it follows that $Z_{2t}-Z_{t}$ can be expressed as:

$$Z_{2t}-Z_{t} = \xi G_{2t}$$ where $\xi\sim$ Bernoulli$(1/2)$ and $G_{2t}\sim $ Geometric random variable of mean $2t$ and independent of $\xi$.

I know the definition of coupling but may I know how this follows? Thanks.

Comment: You could try finding the MGF of $Z_{2t}-Z_{t}$, it should follow quite nicely from there if you factorise it into the MGF of the right hand side. You can thus prove that the MGF of $Z_{2t}-Z_{t}$ is the MGF of a bernoulli times a geometric r.v.

Comment: I think the coupling part is not clear at all. Coupling supposes that you create a certain dependency of the two variables. But since there are many ways they can be made dependent, it is not trivial to find out which way will lead to the desired result. I've made a check with simply independence, and on a first glance, it doesn't seem to lead to the result. But maybe I didn't compute it carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out above, the coupling isn't exactly obvious, and the one we want definitely isn't the independent one.

The usual way of generating a geometric random variable $Z$ with parameter $p$ (and hence, mean $\frac{1}{1-p}$) would be to let $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be iid Ber($p$) variables and define $Z$ to be the first time $n$ such that $X_n=0$.

However, if the $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ instead, we can define $Z$ to be the first time such that $X_n\geq p$ (since $1_{(X_n< p)}$ is Bernoulli with parameter $p$). This yields a very natural coupling between geometric variables of different parameters.

Note that $Z_{2t}$ corresponds to parameter $p=\frac{2t-1}{2t}$ and $Z_t$ corresponds to parameter $q=\frac{t-1}{t}$. Under the above coupling, it's clear that $Z_{2t}\geq Z_t$. Furthermore, we see that, by independence of the $X_n$,
$$
\mathbb{P}(Z_{2t}=Z_t|Z_t=n)=\mathbb{P}\left(X_n\geq \frac{2t-1}{2t} \big|X_n\geq \frac{t-1}{t}\right)=\frac{1-\frac{2t-1}{2t}}{1-\frac{t-1}{t}}=\frac{1}{2}
$$
By the law of total probability, we get that $\mathbb{P}(Z_{2t}>Z_t)=\frac{1}{2}$. Furthermore, we see that for $k\geq 1$, we have, again by independence, that

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(Z_{2t}-Z_t=k) &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(Z_{2t}=n+k|Z_t=n)\mathbb{P}(Z_t=n) \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}\left(X_n\leq \frac{2t-1}{2t}|X_n\geq \frac{t-1}{t}\right) \mathbb{P}\left(X_{n+k}\geq \frac{2t-1}{2t}\right)\prod_{j=1}^{k-1} \mathbb{P}\left( X_{n+j}\leq \frac{2t-1}{2t} \right) \mathbb{P}(Z_t=n) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}(1-p)p^{k-1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(Z_t=n)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}(1-p)p^{k-1}
\end{align}
Which is exactly equal to $\mathbb{P}(\xi G_{2t}=k)$. This shows the desired.

Comment: A couple of questions: When you say $Z$ with parameter $p$, you are referring to the failure probability as $p$. May I know how you got the first two steps in the set of equations in the end? I think the first step should be $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(Z_{2t} = n+k|Z_t = n)P(Z_t = n)$ and I am not sure how you got the second step? Thanks.

Comment: It should definitely be $P(Z_{2t}=n+k|Z_t=n)$. You're absolutely right. For the second step: Well... if $Z_t=n$, then $X_j< q$ for all $j<n$ and $X_n\geq q$. Hence, we also have $X_j<q$. So to have $Z_{2t}=n+k$, we need $X_n<p$ and $X_h<p$ for all $n<p<n+k$ and $X_{n+k}\geqp$. We've only conditioned on the $X_j$ and $X_n$ (since this determined $Z_t$ completely), so we can apply independence to simplify this expression.